# Jmeter perfMon plugin ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using `PerfMon listener` to get graphs for memory, cpu etc. For this I have obeyed the following steps:

**At server:**

The agent i have run on the server and cmd says

> INFO    2016-03-30 15:12:04.206 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
>
> INFO    2016-03-30 15:12:04.269 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
>
> INFO    2016-03-30 15:12:04.269 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.0 started..

I have set java path till bin in the environment variable.
I also tried saving `startAgent.bat` with complete path of the java.exe file

**At client/jmeter plan:**

I have unpacked the `JmeterPlugins` standard jar and now I do see the listener jp@gc perfmon collection metric

In jmeter.properties I have also updated the server ip with port in remote host section

Under jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector, I have added row with host ip its port 4444

**Action:**

Now if I run a small test and expected graph for CPU/memory etc, I just see

> "ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

I doubted firewall could be the issue so I set it off but that also did not help.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your setup at client and server side is correct.

But you have not mentioned opening of port # 4444. So it is most probably the cause of issue.

In order to make it work, Your port#4444 should be visible to JMeter client machine.

To verify if it is visible or not. you can use..

```
http://www.canyouseeme.org/
http://portchecker.co/
```

If it is not visible from Client machine, then you will need to open it. Visit these links to learn how to open port.

```
http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Ports
```

or you may use following from command line

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port" **dir=in** action=allow protocol=TCP **localport=4444**
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port" **dir=out** action=allow protocol=TCP **localport=4444**

Comment: Thanks Arif, But it was a blocking from my network. once they unblocked a port (other than 4444), I am now using it and it works fine.

Comment: Glad that its working you. You can accept   answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you can connect to port 4444 on the machine where Server Agent is running using [telnet](http://www.telnet.org/htm/faq.htm) command like:

```
telnet YOUR_HOST 4444
```

and sending `test` command like

[image]

You should receive `Yep` response. If it is not the case - server side performance monitoring won't work and you will need to establish connectivity between Metrics Collector and Server agent (usually it is enough to open TCP and/or UDP ports 4444 in firewall)

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information